# Integral of $e^{-as/L}e^{b/L\sin(s)}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have been looking for a solution to or some sort of insight into the equation

$$
T(L) = \frac{ \int_0^{2\pi} e^{-(a+b)s/L} e^{b\sin(s)/L} ds }{ L\left(1-e^{-2\pi(a+b)/L} \right) }
$$

where $a, b, L>0$. I have tried to solve the integral analytically, but without luck, and I'm starting to think it's not possible. The equation for $T$ comes from averaging the solution to some ODE, and based on that this I should have

$$
\lim_{L\rightarrow 0}T=\frac{1}{a}
$$

$$
\lim_{L\rightarrow\infty}T=\frac{1}{a+b}
$$

I can solve it numerically, but it doesn't behave nicely near $L=0$. I would greatly appreciate if anyone can provide insight into this quantity (even if it's obvious to someone that the integral can't be done so that I can avoid wasting more time on it).

Comment: Laplace's method  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method

Comment: Ah that's very cool, and almost exactly what I need, but $(a+b)s-b\sin(s)$ doesn't have a maximum on the interval $(0, 2\pi)$

Comment: what about at 0?

Comment: From what I can tell the maximum can't be on the boundary? Like it needs to be approximately a parabola at the maximum

Comment: It works fine on the boundary as wel, it is even simpler since the integral is an exponential, not a Gaussian. My bad for not noticing that wiki does not discuss this.

Comment: Ah I see! In that case I assume you taylor expand inside the exponent to first order and integrate from the bound to infinity/ the other bound or something like that